# Response.Write Horizontal Table from SQL Query using Dataview

Tags: sql, asp.net, dataview, response.write

**Still need help, no answer that has worked yet. Please jump in if you have any ideas.**

I have been trying to get my Response.Write to go Horizontal, however I cannot seem to figure it out.

This is what I currently have (it all sits within a table) and loads from an sql database query using Dataview to get the vehicles I want to display:

```
Response.Write("<tr><td width='200px' colspan='3'><a href='car.aspx?invno=" & invno & "'><image runat='server' src='" + imageurl + "'></image></a></td></tr>")
Response.Write("<tr><td width='5px'>" + year + "</td><td width='10px'>" + make + "</td><td width='100px'>" + model + "</td></tr>")
Response.Write("<tr><td width='200px' colspan='3'>" + mileage + "</td></tr>")
```

However it is Currently giving me this [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJSjC.png)

But what I really want is this [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60eal.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Update**

Ok so I am editing this whole post, as it was overly complicated with what I want. So I am breaking it down to its simplest:

```
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="sqldata" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cars %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 3  ORDER BY NEWID() )">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <div style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'arial';">
                <center>
                <table id="list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="200px">

            <%
                        Dim dv As Data.DataView = CType(sqldata.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), Data.DataView)
                        For Each dr As Data.DataRow In dv.Table.Rows

                        Dim make As String = dr("make")

                            Response.Write("<tr><td>" + make + "</td></tr>")

                    Next
                        %> 
                    </table>

                </center>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So with the code above.. I get a vertical list

```
Ford
Chevy
Toyota
```

But what I want is a Horizontal list

```
Ford    Chevy    Toyota
```

Comment: Try by romoving `Colspan` I suspect currently ur using `colspan=3` which may b the cause of issue.

Comment: @RahulHendawe

Removing the Colspan gives me this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMAQp.png

Answer (score 1):

Create a single row with 3 different columns to achieve your desired result

```
Response.Write("<tr><td width='200px' colspan='3'><a href='car.aspx?invno=" & invno & "'><image runat='server' src='" + imageurl + "'></image></a></td>")
Response.Write("<td width='5px'>" + year + "</td><td width='10px'>" + make + "</td><td width='100px'>" + model + "</td>")
Response.Write("<td width='200px' colspan='3'>" + mileage + "</td></tr>")
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however it didn't give me what I was looking for. I have attached an image to the original post called Picture 3. Any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Clay I cannot see picture 3?

Comment: Updated my whole question, as the tables are not the issue at all.